# Can I see whatsapp messeges on my computer?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

Is there any app that I can install both on my computer and phone (Galaxy s2 plus) that will give me notifications about messages on my computer?
It would be really nice if I could also see the messages, and even better if I could send replys directly from my computer.

Answer (score 3):

Try [PushBullet](http://www.pushbullet.com), it can show you the messages but doesn't have reply features.

#### Update

You can reply from PushBullet directly.
Also, [WhatsApp Web](http://web.whatsapp.com) is available now!